# C2440 compiler error only with new project but not from existing project

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am having weird issue of C2440 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const BYTE [40]' to 'AsmVmxCallType'

https://github.com/tandasat/FU_Hypervisor/blob/master/TestPrograms/SampleHook/SampleHook/fu.h

I am trying to reuse this header file but I get C2440 during compile.
I am currently using VS2019 and I was able to compile https://github.com/tandasat/FU_Hypervisor/blob/master/TestPrograms/SampleHook

However, whenever I import fu.h into other project, i get C2440 type cast error.
I created clean project and imported fu.h and still get same C2440 error

What I dont get is that how come it compiles fine when I use original project but not in my project?

Comment: Where exactly does this happen (file, line, please show here)? Note that the order of includes may be important.

Comment: Really just a 'guess' - but this sort of thing can come about due to the project's "strictness" settings. Try: `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Language` and changing "Conformance Mode" from `Yes (/permissive-)` to `No`.

Comment: #include "fu.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
The error happens on line 230 of fu.h
Error C2440 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const BYTE [40]' to 'AsmVmxCallType'

Comment: "Conformance Mode" from Yes (/permissive-) to No didnt solve the issue

Comment: Hmmm … guesses only work *sometimes*. Second guess - Have you set the 'language' to "C++" instead of "C" (or "default")?

Comment: by changing main file from cpp to c solved the problem! However, I need to use fu.h in cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar error and spent good few hours trying to debug. At the end changing C++ from 14 default to 17 helped: C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard